# Jammed lock screen button

Tags: iphone

My IPhone 4S recently glitched and the notification screen is stuck disabling me from using it at all. I can't shut it off as my lock-screen button is jammed and cannot be used. I'm just wondering if there is anyway I can easily unjam it?

Comment: You need to disassemble your iPhone to "unjam" a stuck button.  If this is outside your scope, you need to take it in for service at either an [Apple Store](http://www.apple.com/retail/) or into an "authorized repiar shop."  Your only other option is to wait for the battery to fully discharge which will obviously shut it off.

Answer (score 1):

Like Alan said, go to a repair shop or an Apple store and ask tell them what is wrong. I wouldn't take it apart yourself as you may damage it, unless you have experience with repairing stuff. To my knowledge, there really isn't an 'easy' way to fix it. If you want to try it yourself, here is a tutorial: http://www.imore.com/how-diy-repair-stuck-or-broken-iphone-4s-power-button